# Show icon to indicate microphone and/or camera are being used

Tags: mac, camera, microphone

For privacy reasons I'd like to know when the camera and/or mic are being used by an app. Is there an app or a built-in feature to shows an icon to indicate that?

Comment: The camera will show a green light when in use. It's (now) hardwired to the camera, so it can' be bypassed.
Also, in Mojave and later, you have to explicitly grant permission for an app to use those devices. Admittedly, once whitelisted, those apps can use it freely.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a product called [Oversight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html) that does this. It’s a donation-ware product meaning it’s completely free but donations to support development are encouraged.

It’s accessed through the menu bar, but if something accesses a device, it will post a notification

[image]

I’ve used this before for users who who were concerned about malware accessing their camera and it worked well.  I haven’t tested in Catalina, but it should work though (IMO) it’s not necessary due to the security permissions model in Catalina. If you don’t grant an app access to a device, it can’t use it.

Answer (score 0):

Micro Snitch by Objective Development:

https://www.obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html